# API that fetches all records from mongoDB using express and mongoskin driver

Tags: mongodb, express, meanjs

I am beginner in Mean stack I am developing an API that fetches all records from mongodb using express. But I am not able to fetch all records from the database. I can't figure what I am doing wrong, I am doing it as follows:

**This is my main app (server.js)**

```js
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
  secret: config.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({
  secret: config.secret
}).unless({
  path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register']
}));

// routes
app.use('/', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
app.use('/register', require('./controllers/register.controller'));
app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users.controller'));

/*// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});*/

// start server
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

This is my `user.controller.js` user will make a request to the api 
*http://localhost:3000/api/users/userList*

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userService = require('services/user.service');

router.get('/userList', getUserList);

module.exports = router;

function getUserList(req, res) {
  userService.userList()
    .then(function(users) {
      if (users) {
        res.send(users);
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
```

This is my `user.service.js` where I am querying the database to fetch all records using mongoskin driver.

```js
var Q = require('q');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/EmployeeForm", {
  native_parser: true
});
db.bind('users');

var service = {};

service.userList = userList;

module.exports = service;

function userList() {
  var deferred = q.defer();

  db.users.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you go to http://localhost:3000/userList ? you dont have route api/userList/userList...

Comment: if i go to localhost:3000/userList it gives cannot Get / userList , there is no problem with the request i am not able to write particular fucntion in express that fetches all records from mongo db database.

Comment: Hm..Can you show main app where you run express app and enables all routes.

Comment: Oh so your code dont return results? correct

Comment: This api is not called from main app.

Comment: I see issue with mongoDB code when you trying to get all records.. But i dont understand if this is the only problem or you have more issues. That's why i want to check main server file.

Comment: yes right now i am just fetching the records from the database and testing it on restclient to see if the records are fetched properly

Comment: i have added main app but my flow goes like this there is a login form i login is the application then there is a dashboard which contains a form that saves employee details . Now i want to get all records from database and show it on the frontend

Comment: Hm..server.jslooks good. So my question does it goes into userList function() ? or where it stops?

Comment: yes it will go into getUserList function of user.controller.js and from that the the userList of user.service.js will get call which will query the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think it's find issue.

MongoDB find method return cursor by default.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

From https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin they use method toArray which will transform cursor into array of objects like this
`db.find.toArray(callback)`

So try like this in userList()

```
function userList() {
  var deferred = q.defer();

  db.users.find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
     err ? deferred.reject(err) :  deferred.resolve(docs);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understood what you did in user.service.js but what about user.controller.js how to handle a userlist which will be returned . And i am not able to test whether the records are being retrieved from the database

Comment: Well if there will be an error in query your promise just rejects and you will catch that in controller..If all will be ok..then you will get array of users from toArray method and res.send(users) -> will return that array to from-end. So if array will be empty or something like this is just query issue.